# MaterialComponents randomly gives colours to status bar and Toolbar despite lack of custom colour attributes defined

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-theme, mdc-components

Why does `MaterialComponents` apply random colours when I've not specified any colours in the `colors.xml` file? Is there a way to remove those colours for the Day Mode so that the colour white is shown? I understand that `MaterialComponents` allows better customisation of themes, but I specifically don't need primary and secondary colour schemes. This never happened before when I was using `AppCompat`.

**values/themes.xml** & **night/themes.xml**

*when using AppCompat*

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

*when using MaterialComponents*

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
</resources>
```

**Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar theme**

[image]

**Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar theme**

[image]

**XML (CollapsingToolbarLayout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myAppBarLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCollapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

**XML (main layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/collapsing_toolbar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [the doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md).
The Material Components Library provides some default colors.

[For example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/themes_base.xml#L82):

```
 <style name="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents" parent="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge">    
    <!-- Colors -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/design_default_color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/design_default_color_primary_dark</item>
```

[which is](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/values/colors.xml#L20):

```
<color name="design_default_color_primary">#6200EE</color>
```

And the default `Toolbar` background color is based on the `colorPrimary`.

You have to **override** them in your app theme.

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"/>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
 </style>
```